# use ctrl-click on vscode to go to implementation instead of peek definition

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with a .svelte file.

When I ctrl-click it shows me the definition in a panel below the line.
Same think happens if I right click and choose `go to definition` or `peek -> peek definition`, which is a bit odd.

I'd like ctrl-click to open a new tab with the definition (that is what happens if I right click and select go to implementation)

btw, I think my `go to definition` is not working so well, as it's just doing the same as peek.

Comment: You figure out the issue? I've been trying to figure out how to get Ctrl+Click to actually take me to the definition. Sometimes it will work. Sometimes it doesn't know anything about what I'm clicking on. If I'm on the .ts file it works normally. If I'm in an .html file that is where the problems usually occur.

Comment: Not yet, I'll wait a couple days before opening an issue, to see if someone else found the solution

Answer (score 22):

There seems to be a new setting `editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions` which, if set to `peek` (as is the default) will open a peek *even if* the definition is unique. This may be a bug but setting it to `goto` solves it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To avoid peek panel below the code when ctrl + click is pressed, change this setting in vscode user settings.
File -> Preferences -> Settings -> User: **definitionLinkOpensInPeek**
Uncheck the check box.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: doesn't work on my end, peek window still show even when unchecked. i'm using `Version: 1.81.1 (Universal)`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider also adding the corresponding language extension according to the programming language you are using, I added the language extension and it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider downloading PHP intelephense, a vscode extension for PHP.